# Create topmost fullscreen window without titlebar, but desktop's taskbar must be visible

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

I'm using WinUI3, and I need to create topmost fullscreen borderless window without titlebar, but taskbar must be visible. My window must be always on top, it should not hide when I press Win+D
I tried to set AppWindow's Presenter to CompactOverlay and set size manually, but titlebar is visible. I tried to set AppWindow's Presenter to Fullscreen, but it hides taskbar, if i set size, window can be hidden.
[image: Example of window, which i need(My window is all gray area)]

Comment: Could you give an example of how your borderless window is defined?

Comment: @mm8, yes, i added it to question

Comment: I think he meant how it is defined in code.

Comment: In code, OverlappedPresenter can enable/disable border using SetBorderAndTitleBar method

Comment: Maybe your app should be an [Appbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars?redirectedfrom=MSDN) that takes up the entire "desktop area" (anything that is not the main windows taskbar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _presenter = this.AppWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;
        this.Activated += MainWindow_Activated;
    }

    private OverlappedPresenter? _presenter;

    private void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_presenter is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _presenter.Maximize();
        _presenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(hasBorder: false, hasTitleBar: false);
        _presenter.IsAlwaysOnTop = true;
    }
}
```